# collapse all tabs when button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

script:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Tabs").tabs();

  $("#close").click(function () {
    $("#Tabs").tabs({collapsible: true,active: false });
 });
```

html:

```
 <div id="Tabs">
    <ul>
     <li><a href="#form_1">Details</a></li>
     <li class="end"><a href="#form_2" style="width: 82px !important">Show Map</a></li>
    </ul>
   <div >
     <div id="form_1" style="color:Black !important;" >
       <div class="bg">
         form 1
         </div>
        </div>
       <div id="form_2" style="color:Black !important;" >
       <div class="bg">
         form 2
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
       </div>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close" id="close" >close</a>
```

I'm using jquery Tabs and i am  trying to close all opened tabs when i click on `close` but it's not working any idea ?

Comment: So what is this `tabs`? Is it some kind of jQuery plugin?

Comment: Do you mean jqueryui tabs?

Comment: This works fine check http://jsfiddle.net/5dxE6/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this **[jsFiddle..](http://jsfiddle.net/7VPvX/8/)**

The code is like below

**JQuery function...**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Tabs").tabs();

  $("#close").click(function () {
    $("#Tabs").tabs({
        hide: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 500
        },
        show: {
            effect: "fade",
            duration: 500
        },
        collapsible: true,
        active: false
    });
 });
});
```

**HTML code...**

```
<div id="Tabs">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#form_1">
        Details
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="end">
      <a href="#form_2" style="width: 82px !important">
        Show Map
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div >
    <div id="form_1" style="color:Black !important;" >
      <div class="bg">
        form 1
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="form_2" style="color:Black !important;" >
      <div class="bg">
        form 2
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="close" id="close" >
  close
</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation:

> When set to true, the **active panel** can be closed.

Since jQuery doesn't expose a method to close all tabs, you will have to do it manually:

```
$("#close").click(function () {
    $('.ui-tabs-panel').hide()
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4mtM4/